# NuGet Dependency Reference links using (full) User Path in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

For some reason, in my iOS project...the SkiaSharp NuGet library (reference) links-in using the full directory-path.

- What causes this?
- How do I fix it?

...the other projects do not do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually**, you have already installed the package in your project and the warning you faced is an issue of the nuget package itself and you should contact with the author. You are not the only one to face the issue. And other staff also get this abnormal behavior.

I also faced the issue in my side and actually when you have this node in your `xxx.csproj` file

```
<PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp">
      <Version>2.80.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

It means that you have installed the **SkiaSharp** nuget package successfully.

[image]

The real problem is this file

```
C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\skiasharp\2.80.2\build\xamarinios1.0\SkiaSharp.targets
```

and

```
C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\skiasharp\2.80.2\buildTransitive\xamarinios1.0\SkiaSharp.targets
```

[image]

The **NativeReference** cannot be recognized by **MSBuild** due to some reasons. It is quite strange.

[image]

The `$(_SkiaSharpNativeLibraryRootDir)` cannot be parsed.

**For a further survey**，I found that there is an issue on Vs, NativeReference node cannot recognize `$(xxx)` msbuild property value. When I input the full path of it, it can work well.

I also [reported the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1251187/why-nativereference-cannot-recoginze-msbuild-prope.html) and if you are interested in it, you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention.

=====================

So you have to contact with the package author and Microsoft Team under my reported link.

Since the process may take a long time, as a suggestion, you could try the following steps which be complex but can solve it:

**1)** **delete** these node under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\skiasharp\2.80.2\build\xamarinios1.0\SkiaSharp.targets`

and

`C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\skiasharp\2.80.2\buildTransitive\xamarinios1.0\SkiaSharp.targets`:

```
    <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(ShouldIncludeNativeSkiaSharp)' != 'False' ">
        <NativeReference Include="$(_SkiaSharpNativeLibraryRootDir)libSkiaSharp.framework" Kind="Framework" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

**2)** enter your `xxx.csproj` file of your ios app and add these:

```
<ItemGroup>
            
    <NativeReference Include="C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\skiasharp\2.80.2\build\xamarinios1.0\libSkiaSharp.framework" Kind="Framework"></NativeReference>

</ItemGroup>
```

**3)** after that, close VS and restart your project to enable the changes.