# How to Remove local nuget references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, realm

I added realm package to my project and it works fine but for some reason it also added some not valid local dependencies which i cannot remove. I tried to remove them manually from csproj file but there is no trace of them. How can i get rid of them?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added [RuntimeIdentifier xml node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) on csproj file on a non-sdk net framework project.

That is the cause. And you should note that `RuntimeIdentifier` works for new sdk `net core` cross-platform project rather than your non-sdk `net framework` windows project.

`RuntimeIdentifier` does not work for non-sdk net framework projects.

**So** you have to remove these on `csproj` file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

When I remove it, all work well.

## **Update**

It is [a well-known issue which I have reported before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64772487/nuget-dependency-reference-links-using-full-user-path-in-visual-studio/64782378#64782378).

The problem is here:

`C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\realm\10.1.1\build\Realm.props` and then open that file, you will see:

[image]

You have two points which needed to care:

**1) NativeReference** works for ios apps rather than android apps, actually, you could just delete the `NativeReference` node but for the inclusiveness and comprehensiveness of the nuget package, it is not advisable to delete it.

**2) NativeReference** cannot recognize the value of MSBuild property. You can't pass a property value in there. Just as [my link hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64772487/nuget-dependency-reference-links-using-full-user-path-in-visual-studio/64782378#64782378).

**First of all**, the `itemgroup condition` will indeed be processed by vs according to the conditions when it is built, but when it is not built, it will ignore the condition to check its content to determine whether it is valid, but because your Android project has not been able to recognize the `nativereference` , So the problem has always existed.

**In order to** skip this detection mechanism, you'd better use `choose, when`. And in this scenario, you are using an **Android** project, so there is no need to consider the problem that the `nativereference` cannot identify the property.

**Suggestion One**

modify the `Realm.props` to:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_RealmNugetNativePath Condition="'$(_RealmNugetNativePath)' == ''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\native\</_RealmNugetNativePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
<Choose>
<When Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'Xamarin.iOS'">
<ItemGroup>
 <NativeReference Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)ios\universal\realm-wrappers.framework">
      <Kind>Framework</Kind>
      <SmartLink>False</SmartLink>
    </NativeReference>
</ItemGroup>
</When>
<When Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'Xamarin.Mac'">

 <ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)..\runtimes\osx-x64\native\librealm-wrappers.dylib">
      <Kind>Dynamic</Kind>
    </NativeReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
</Choose>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'Xamarin.iOS'">
   
    <Content Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)ios\Realm.dll.config">
      <Link>Realm.dll.config</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
 
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'MonoAndroid'">
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)android\armeabi-v7a\librealm-wrappers.so">
      <Link>$(_RealmNugetNativePath)android\armeabi-v7a\librealm-wrappers.so</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)android\x86\librealm-wrappers.so">
      <Link>$(_RealmNugetNativePath)android\x86\librealm-wrappers.so</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
    <!-- 64bit -->
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)android\arm64-v8a\librealm-wrappers.so">
      <Link>$(_RealmNugetNativePath)android\arm64-v8a\librealm-wrappers.so</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)android\x86_64\librealm-wrappers.so">
      <Link>$(_RealmNugetNativePath)android\x86_64\librealm-wrappers.so</Link>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETFramework'">
    <None Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)..\runtimes\win-x86\native\realm-wrappers.dll">
      <Link>lib\win32\x86\realm-wrappers.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="$(_RealmNugetNativePath)..\runtimes\win-x64\native\realm-wrappers.dll">
      <Link>lib\win32\x64\realm-wrappers.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Suggestion Two**

**2)** If you use an IOS app further, you have to try these:

**a)** delete two `NativeReference` nodes directly under `Realm.props` file

**b)** then add these on `ios.csoroj` file:

```
<Choose>
<When Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'Xamarin.iOS'">

<ItemGroup>
<NativeReference Include="C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\realm\10.1.1\native\ios\universal\realm-wrappers.framework" Kind="Framework" SmartLink="False">
</NativeReference>

</ItemGroup>
</When>
<When Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'Xamarin.Mac'">
     <ItemGroup>
<NativeReference Include="C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\realm\10.1.1\runtimes\osx-x64\native\librealm-wrappers.dylib" Kind="Dynamic">
</NativeReference>
</ItemGroup>
  </When>

</Choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for your message i checkd my csproj file and there is no such entry inside. Also i should mention my project is Xamarin-android project

Comment: @whd, sorry for that. And it is quite an issue and please check my answer:)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on your project, select `Unload Project`.
2. Select the unloaded project, you'll see a xml file opened.
3. Look for `<ItemGroup>` which holds the list of references.
4. Delete the items that you don't need anymore.
5. Save the file. Right click on the project and `Reload` it.